# Remote port forwarding to pool databse

Tags: postgresql, ssh, portforwarding

I have a problem to pool some datas from my PostgreSQL database into my MongoDB local database

My PostgreSQL is on a remote ubuntu server, so i've try to make a port forwarding on my local machine with the command

`ssh -R 5432:127.0.0.1:12345 user@remote_ip`

But when i try to connect to my PostgreSQL database from my local machine with indicate port (12345), it looks like there is nothing on my local 12345 port

So, am I doing something wrong ? If someone can help me

If you need more details, do not hesitate to ask me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please indicate which command you use to transfer the data and on which machine you start it.

Comment: I think you have the forwarding the wrong way around. Try -L 12345 ...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't use a command. After my port forwarding, i should run a nodeJS script to transfert data from PostgreSQL to MongoDB

Comment: @RichardHuxton Can i ask you to write me the whole command please ?

Comment: You presumably want to route your local port 12345 to 5432 on the remote server, so `ssh -L 12345:127.0.0.1:5432 ...`. Then anything trying to open a connection to port 12345 on your machine will be tunneled through to PostgreSQL on the remote server.